# Add to Custom Entity Content on Node add/update

Tags: 8, entities

I am new to Drupal. Now, learning drupal 8.

I have added a module from command `drupal generate:module` named 'my_module`

I have added an entity for `my_module`:

```
drupal generate:entity:content
//bundle "NO"
```

**What I want**

I would like to add/insert in to this entity on every **Node** add/update.

I have got this code into my `my_module.module`

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'my_module_node_form_submit';
      }
    }
}

function my_module_node_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

   $url = $node->field_website->uri; //my node field
   $name = $node->field_com->value; //my node field

   //HOW TO ADD $url, $name IN TO above custom ENTITY
}
```

My entity table:

**1: my_module**

```
id
uuid
langcode
```

**2: my_module_field_data**

```
id PrimaryIndex
langcode PrimaryIndex
name
url
status
created
changed
default_langcode Index
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do like this**

*Suppose your entity name is **my_entity**.*

```
<?php
use Drupal\my_module\Entity\my_entity;

function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
            $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'my_module_node_form_submit';
        }
    }
}

function my_module_node_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

    $url = $node->field_website->uri;
    $name = $node->field_com->value;

    // Now to check    
    //Generate my_entity entity.
    $entity = my_entity::create(
               [
                 'label' => 'token',
                 'id' => $node->id(),
                 'status' => true,
                 'name'=> $url,
                  "url" => $name,
                  "created" => time()
               ]
         );
    $entity->save();
}
```

**To update enity:**

```
$entity = my_entity::load('content entity id');
$entity->set("name", 'name value');
$entity->set("url", 'url value');
$entity->save();
```